# How to apply SVProgressHUD in a UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, svprogresshud

I have this code, but doesn't work and i don't know why?

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)web
{
    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading..."];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)web
{
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
}
```

Comment: the svprogresshud doesn't appear when the uiwebwiew load

Answer (score 0):

Your question is far away from being complete enough to be answered properly, but if I have to guess I'd say that those methods are never being called.

You should set your `UIWebView` delegate either in Interface Builder or programmatically.